# How to handle AccessDeniedException in Spring Security?

Tags: spring, spring-security

i am using **spring security 3**, and i want whenever the **AccessDeniedException** is thrown, the user get's redirected to specific page:

```
org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
    at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:71)
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:203)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:106)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:97)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:78)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:112)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:35)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:177)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:187)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:79)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:169)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:198)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:405)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:964)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:515)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

so i tried to use **access-denied-handler**
and here's the handler:

```
@Service("accessDeniedHandler")
public class AccessDeniedHandler extends AccessDeniedHandlerImpl {

    Log log = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

    @Override
    public void handle(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, AccessDeniedException exception)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        log.info("############### Access Denied Handler!");
        setErrorPage("/accessDenied");
        super.handle(request, response, exception);
    }

}
```

- **applicationSecurity.xml**:

  ```
    <beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"  
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"  
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd">

  <http use-expressions="true"  auto-config="true" >

  <session-management session-fixation-protection="none"/>

      <remember-me  token-validity-seconds="1209600"/>

      <intercept-url pattern="/accessDenied" access="permitAll"/>

      <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll"/>
      <intercept-url pattern="/j_spring_security_check" access="permitAll" />

      <intercept-url pattern="/faces/javax.faces.resource/**" access="permitAll"/>
      <intercept-url pattern="/xmlhttp/**" access="permitAll" />
      <intercept-url pattern="/resources/**" access="permitAll" />

      <intercept-url pattern="**/faces/javax.faces.resource/**" access="permitAll"/>
      <intercept-url pattern="**/xmlhttp/**" access="permitAll" />
      <intercept-url pattern="**/resources/**" access="permitAll" />


      <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />

  <access-denied-handler ref="accessDeniedHandler" />

  <!-- tried the error page too with no luck -->

  <!-- 
  <access-denied-handler error-page="/accessDenied" />
  -->


  </http>
  </beans:beans>
  ```

but the **issue:** is that when the exception is thrown, it doesn't enter the accessDeniedHandler class, please advise.

**UPDATE**: i tried the solution of the exceptions bean, and still getting same behavior, exception is thrown, but no redirection occurs to accessDenied page.

**Logs**:

```
2012-01-08/12:33:43.610 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG Converted URL to lowercase, from: '/'; to: '/'
2012-01-08/12:33:43.610 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG Converted URL to lowercase, from: '/'; to: '/'
2012-01-08/12:33:43.610 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG Candidate is: '/'; pattern is /**; matched=true
2012-01-08/12:33:43.610 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG Candidate is: '/'; pattern is /**; matched=true
2012-01-08/12:33:43.610 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG / at position 1 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2012-01-08/12:33:43.610 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG / at position 1 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2012-01-08/12:33:43.611 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG HttpSession returned null object for SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT
2012-01-08/12:33:43.611 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG HttpSession returned null object for SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT
2012-01-08/12:33:43.611 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@5b7da0d1. A new one will be created.
2012-01-08/12:33:43.611 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@5b7da0d1. A new one will be created.
2012-01-08/12:33:43.611 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG / at position 2 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
2012-01-08/12:33:43.611 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG / at position 2 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
2012-01-08/12:33:43.611 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG / at position 3 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter'
2012-01-08/12:33:43.611 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG / at position 3 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter'
2012-01-08/12:33:43.611 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG / at position 4 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'BasicAuthenticationFilter'
2012-01-08/12:33:43.611 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG / at position 4 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'BasicAuthenticationFilter'
2012-01-08/12:33:43.611 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG / at position 5 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
2012-01-08/12:33:43.611 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG / at position 5 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
2012-01-08/12:33:43.611 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG pathInfo: both null (property equals)
2012-01-08/12:33:43.611 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG pathInfo: both null (property equals)
2012-01-08/12:33:43.611 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG queryString: both null (property equals)
2012-01-08/12:33:43.611 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG queryString: both null (property equals)
2012-01-08/12:33:43.611 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG requestURI: arg1=/MyApp/; arg2=/MyApp/ (property equals)
2012-01-08/12:33:43.611 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG requestURI: arg1=/MyApp/; arg2=/MyApp/ (property equals)
2012-01-08/12:33:43.611 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG serverPort: arg1=8080; arg2=8080 (property equals)
2012-01-08/12:33:43.611 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG serverPort: arg1=8080; arg2=8080 (property equals)
2012-01-08/12:33:43.611 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG requestURL: arg1=http://localhost:8080/MyApp/; arg2=http://localhost:8080/MyApp/ (property equals)
2012-01-08/12:33:43.611 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG requestURL: arg1=http://localhost:8080/MyApp/; arg2=http://localhost:8080/MyApp/ (property equals)
2012-01-08/12:33:43.611 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG scheme: arg1=http; arg2=http (property equals)
2012-01-08/12:33:43.611 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG scheme: arg1=http; arg2=http (property equals)
2012-01-08/12:33:43.612 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG serverName: arg1=localhost; arg2=localhost (property equals)
2012-01-08/12:33:43.612 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG serverName: arg1=localhost; arg2=localhost (property equals)
2012-01-08/12:33:43.612 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG contextPath: arg1=/MyApp; arg2=/MyApp (property equals)
2012-01-08/12:33:43.612 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG contextPath: arg1=/MyApp; arg2=/MyApp (property equals)
2012-01-08/12:33:43.612 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG servletPath: arg1=/; arg2=/ (property equals)
2012-01-08/12:33:43.612 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG servletPath: arg1=/; arg2=/ (property equals)
2012-01-08/12:33:43.612 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG Removing DefaultSavedRequest from session if present
2012-01-08/12:33:43.612 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG Removing DefaultSavedRequest from session if present
2012-01-08/12:33:43.612 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG / at position 6 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
2012-01-08/12:33:43.612 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG / at position 6 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
2012-01-08/12:33:43.612 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG / at position 7 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RememberMeAuthenticationFilter'
2012-01-08/12:33:43.612 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG / at position 7 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RememberMeAuthenticationFilter'
2012-01-08/12:33:43.612 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG / at position 8 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
2012-01-08/12:33:43.612 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG / at position 8 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
2012-01-08/12:33:43.612 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@90576bf4: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@21a2c: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: 7F9F9C2E2922F5072EE36B6FBCFE8837; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
2012-01-08/12:33:43.612 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@90576bf4: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@21a2c: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: 7F9F9C2E2922F5072EE36B6FBCFE8837; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
2012-01-08/12:33:43.612 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG / at position 9 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
2012-01-08/12:33:43.612 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG / at position 9 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
2012-01-08/12:33:43.613 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG / at position 10 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
2012-01-08/12:33:43.613 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG / at position 10 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
2012-01-08/12:33:43.613 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG Converted URL to lowercase, from: '/'; to: '/'
2012-01-08/12:33:43.613 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG Converted URL to lowercase, from: '/'; to: '/'
2012-01-08/12:33:43.613 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG Candidate is: '/'; pattern is /accessdenied; matched=false
2012-01-08/12:33:43.613 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG Candidate is: '/'; pattern is /accessdenied; matched=false
2012-01-08/12:33:43.613 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG Candidate is: '/'; pattern is /login; matched=false
2012-01-08/12:33:43.613 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG Candidate is: '/'; pattern is /login; matched=false
2012-01-08/12:33:43.613 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG Candidate is: '/'; pattern is /j_spring_security_check; matched=false
2012-01-08/12:33:43.613 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG Candidate is: '/'; pattern is /j_spring_security_check; matched=false
2012-01-08/12:33:43.613 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG Candidate is: '/'; pattern is /faces/javax.faces.resource/**; matched=false
2012-01-08/12:33:43.613 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG Candidate is: '/'; pattern is /faces/javax.faces.resource/**; matched=false
2012-01-08/12:33:43.613 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG Candidate is: '/'; pattern is /xmlhttp/**; matched=false
2012-01-08/12:33:43.613 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG Candidate is: '/'; pattern is /xmlhttp/**; matched=false
2012-01-08/12:33:43.613 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG Candidate is: '/'; pattern is /resources/**; matched=false
2012-01-08/12:33:43.613 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG Candidate is: '/'; pattern is /resources/**; matched=false
2012-01-08/12:33:43.613 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG Candidate is: '/'; pattern is **/faces/javax.faces.resource/**; matched=false
2012-01-08/12:33:43.613 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG Candidate is: '/'; pattern is **/faces/javax.faces.resource/**; matched=false
2012-01-08/12:33:43.613 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG Candidate is: '/'; pattern is **/xmlhttp/**; matched=false
2012-01-08/12:33:43.613 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG Candidate is: '/'; pattern is **/xmlhttp/**; matched=false
2012-01-08/12:33:43.613 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG Candidate is: '/'; pattern is **/resources/**; matched=false
2012-01-08/12:33:43.613 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG Candidate is: '/'; pattern is **/resources/**; matched=false
2012-01-08/12:33:43.615 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG Candidate is: '/'; pattern is /**; matched=true
2012-01-08/12:33:43.615 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG Candidate is: '/'; pattern is /**; matched=true
2012-01-08/12:33:43.615 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /; Attributes: [isAuthenticated()]
2012-01-08/12:33:43.615 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /; Attributes: [isAuthenticated()]
2012-01-08/12:33:43.615 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@90576bf4: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@21a2c: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: 7F9F9C2E2922F5072EE36B6FBCFE8837; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
2012-01-08/12:33:43.615 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@90576bf4: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@21a2c: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: 7F9F9C2E2922F5072EE36B6FBCFE8837; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
2012-01-08/12:33:43.615 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@338652ff, returned: -1
2012-01-08/12:33:43.615 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@338652ff, returned: -1
2012-01-08/12:33:43.615 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG Access is denied (user is anonymous); redirecting to authentication entry point
org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
    at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:71)
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:203)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:106)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:97)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:78)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:112)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:35)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:177)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:187)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:79)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:169)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:198)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:405)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:964)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:515)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
2012-01-08/12:33:43.615 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG Access is denied (user is anonymous); redirecting to authentication entry point
org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the access denied page is a simple page that does not need a controller, you can do it this way:

```
<!-- This bean resolves specific types of exceptions to corresponding logical
    - view names for error views. The default behavior of DispatcherServlet -
    is to propagate all exceptions to the servlet container: this will happen
    - here with all other types of exceptions. -->
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver"
    p:defaultErrorView="uncaughtException">
    <property name="exceptionMappings">
        <props>
            <prop key=".DataAccessException">dataAccessFailure</prop>
            <prop key=".NoSuchRequestHandlingMethodException">resourceNotFound</prop>
            <prop key=".TypeMismatchException">resourceNotFound</prop>
            <prop key=".MissingServletRequestParameterException">resourceNotFound</prop>
            <prop key=".AccessDeniedException">accessDenied</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

 <!-- remove this if you need a controller -->
 <mvc:view-controller path="/accessDenied" />

 <security:intercept-url pattern="/accessDenied" access="permitAll" />
```

---

Another way is using **`AccessDeniedHander`**. You would only need to configure the `spring-security:access-denied-handler` tag within the `spring-security:http` tag. *This way seems to work only if the access restriction is configured by an `security:intercept-url`, but not if it is done at the service level (for example, by annotations).*

```
<security:http auto-config="true" ... >
  ...
  <security:access-denied-handler error-page="/myAccessDeniedPage"/>
</security:http>
```

Comment: will this configuration work with method level security ? i mean if user is trying to invoke a service or web service with not enough permission, will he get redirected to the accessDenied page ?

Comment: It depends only on the exception, no matter how it is thrown.

Comment: can you please take a look at my xml configuration above, because first thing i tried was the `access-denied-handler error-page` and it doesn't work, i get the exception thrown and user is not getting redirected to the access denied page.

Comment: @Msaleh: in the comment I was talking about the exception resolver way. Anyway I have also tested the `access-denied-handler` way and (to my supprise) this works only if the accedd denied is defined by an `security:intercept-url` but not by an exception thrown by an annotation or explicit. -- So I would recommend to use the exception handler way.

Comment: can i use the first solution without using spring MVC ?

Comment: and what is the use of this tag please `<mvc:view-controller path="/accessDenied" />`

Comment: What do you mean without MVC? You already using Spring WEB (see your stack trace)

Comment: mvc:view-controller  this is some simple mapping to map an url to an jsp page without explicite controller

Comment: i mean i don't have explicit configuration for spring mvc xml file.

Comment: You do not need an extra configuration file

Comment: @Msaleh: I do not understand the question in the last comment. And I do not understand how it is related the general problem.

Comment: i tried the bean solution exactly as you provided, and i still get the same behavior, i added logs to the post.

Comment: I tried both the SimpleMappingExceptionResolver and the access-denied-handler tag, but the AccessDeniedException is still thrown. I'm using @Secured at class level though (my goal is to have authorization on views in Vaadin).

Comment: @Roger: Raise a new question that descipe your problem in detail

Answer (score 8):

Programmatically solution:

```
@Order(1)
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    //
    // ...
    //

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(new AccessDeniedHandlerImpl() {
            @Override
            public void handle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AccessDeniedException accessDeniedException) throws IOException, ServletException {
                super.handle(request, response, accessDeniedException);

                // 
                // Your Code Here
                //

            }

            @Override
            public void setErrorPage(String errorPage) {
                super.setErrorPage(errorPage);

                // 
                // Your Code Here
                //

            }
        });

        //
        // ...
        //

    }

    //
    // ...
    //

}
```

Answer (score 1):

> 2012-01-08/12:33:43.615 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG Access is denied (user is anonymous); redirecting to authentication entry point
>   org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied

It looks like your login page (or some elements of that page) is only available to logged in users.

Comment: the case is that i want to access a protected page (and also require special role) after session is over, and then an accessDenied exception is thrown.

Comment: @Msaleh: realy, all the time the problem is that the session is over?

Comment: ,session is over= anonymous role so it's related to roles anyway, this is as far as i understand, what i am missing here ?

Comment: A AccessDeniedException that occured if a user is logged in, is handled completely different as when the user is not logged in. In the later case spring security will catch the exception and redirect the user to the login page.

Comment: but any ideas how to handle that issue when not authorized `ajax request` (not http request) is done when user is not logged in, what happens is that access denied exception is thrown but no redirection to login page occurs, redirection occur only for http requests.

Comment: Sorry: I can not confirm this behavior, I my application the ajax-request gets an redirect to the login page - and this causes the ajax-clinet to an failuere when try to parse the response (because is is not the expected json object)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue of redirection after session timeout using [sessionManagementFilter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/session-mgmt.html) as in this post:

http://www.icesoft.org/wiki/display/ICE/Spring+Security+3.0

Answer (score 0):

```
DEBUG Access is denied (user is anonymous)
```

if you look at spring code you will see, that spring calls accessDeniedHandler only for non anonymous user, so mine solution was something like

```
<security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="@storeAccessService.initForExpiredXmlHttpRequest() and _other_rules_here
```

where inside initForExpiredXmlHttpRequest() I was doing

```
HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()).getRequest();
//logic to filter
UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken sessionExpiredAuthentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                "session-expired", "session-expired");
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(sessionExpiredAuthentication);
```