# Spring version update causing issue (Access denied)

Tags: spring, spring-security

In our project we have to update the spring jars to the latest provided across our company.
In this process I updated spring jars from 3.1.1 to 3.2.4 and spring security jars(spring-security-config,spring-security-core,spring-security-taglibs,spring-security-web) from 3.1.1 to 3.1.4
Once this update is done, My application is behaving in a strange manner.
If I am idle on the application for few secs (10sec), I am getting access denied and my application is redirecting to login page.
I rolled back spring security related jar back to 3.1.1 after which it is behaving good.
But I have to update security jars also 
Can someone let me know the reason why I am ending in that scenario with spring security 3.1.4 jars?

Comment: please provide more details like error details and compilation steps.

Comment: 2013-11-22 05:56:59,074 2815782 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased] (http-8080-27:) Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@ac8a8, returned: -1
2013-11-22 05:56:59,074 2815782 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter] (http-8080-27:) Access is denied (user is anonymous); redirecting to authentication entry point
org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:83)

Comment: check this link:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8742842/how-to-handle-accessdeniedexception-in-spring-security

Comment: Verified the link you provided. But havn't got any answer for the issue I was facing..

Answer (score 0):

we had a same issue one of my senior developer has workaround by pinging or hitting all the application URL before reaching the idle window time for 10s or 15s , then application was stable now , but this was an very annoying behavior!..

we are using spring-security for 3.1.0.release...

Comment: Is this a question or an answer. Please rephrase to only provide your solution. (That is: ping regularly)