# Spring Security Sample of CAS Integration not working

Tags: spring-security, cas, access-denied

I'm trying to implement CAS Server Integration with Spring Security and the sample project that I'm using is from [Spring's Official Github](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/tree/master/samples) Repository.

But when I run the sample, I'm getting this error. Please help me with this. It's annoying that Spring Documentation's sample projects have error in themselves.

```
org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
    at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:83) ~[spring-security-core-4.0.3.CI-SNAPSHOT.jar:4.0.3.CI-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:232) ~[spring-security-core-4.0.3.CI-SNAPSHOT.jar:4.0.3.CI-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.CI-SNAPSHOT.jar:4.0.3.CI-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.CI-SNAPSHOT.jar:4.0.3.CI-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.CI-SNAPSHOT.jar:4.0.3.CI-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.CI-SNAPSHOT.jar:4.0.3.CI-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.CI-SNAPSHOT.jar:4.0.3.CI-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:122) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.CI-SNAPSHOT.jar:4.0.3.CI-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.CI-SNAPSHOT.jar:4.0.3.CI-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.CI-SNAPSHOT.jar:4.0.3.CI-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.CI-SNAPSHOT.jar:4.0.3.CI-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.CI-SNAPSHOT.jar:4.0.3.CI-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.CI-SNAPSHOT.jar:4.0.3.CI-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:48) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.CI-SNAPSHOT.jar:4.0.3.CI-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.CI-SNAPSHOT.jar:4.0.3.CI-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:205) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.CI-SNAPSHOT.jar:4.0.3.CI-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.CI-SNAPSHOT.jar:4.0.3.CI-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.jasig.cas.client.session.SingleSignOutFilter.doFilter(SingleSignOutFilter.java:100) [cas-client-core-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.CI-SNAPSHOT.jar:4.0.3.CI-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:120) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.CI-SNAPSHOT.jar:4.0.3.CI-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.CI-SNAPSHOT.jar:4.0.3.CI-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:120) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.CI-SNAPSHOT.jar:4.0.3.CI-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.CI-SNAPSHOT.jar:4.0.3.CI-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.CI-SNAPSHOT.jar:4.0.3.CI-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.CI-SNAPSHOT.jar:4.0.3.CI-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.CI-SNAPSHOT.jar:4.0.3.CI-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.CI-SNAPSHOT.jar:4.0.3.CI-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.CI-SNAPSHOT.jar:4.0.3.CI-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.CI-SNAPSHOT.jar:4.0.3.CI-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.CI-SNAPSHOT.jar:4.0.3.CI-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.CI-SNAPSHOT.jar:4.0.3.CI-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344) [spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261) [spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243) [catalina.jar:7.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) [catalina.jar:7.0.34]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:85) [spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243) [catalina.jar:7.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) [catalina.jar:7.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222) [catalina.jar:7.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123) [catalina.jar:7.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472) [catalina.jar:7.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171) [catalina.jar:7.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99) [catalina.jar:7.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936) [catalina.jar:7.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118) [catalina.jar:7.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407) [catalina.jar:7.0.34]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.34]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.34]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.34]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_79]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_79]
```

Answer (score 0):

This same question is already been answered in stackoverflow, please refer
[How to handle AccessDeniedException in Spring Security?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8742842/how-to-handle-accessdeniedexception-in-spring-security)

Comment: Thanks for the answer Sir, but my question is how to prevent access denied exception. This answer explains how to display a specified page when AccessDeniedException occurs.